# Android Volley framework

Tags: android, android-volley

After watching this year's Google IO session: ["Google I/O 2013 - Volley: Easy, Fast Networking for Android"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhv8l9F44qo)

I've decided to replace my current RESTful implementation in favor of using Volley.
As suggested I have cloned the repository from googlecode into my project and included it as a library project.

Everything works great and this library is indeed awesome, but how could I tell when it's time to update it when there are no official releases only commits on master branch? Who is in charge to announce which versions are stable and which aren't? Is there any official blog where I could get updates on this framework?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> how could I tell when it's time to update it when there are no official releases only commits on master branch?

Presumably, you need review the changes yourself and determine if you want them.

> Who is in charge to announce which versions are stable and which aren't?

In theory, Google. In practice, probably nobody at present.

> Is there any official blog where I could get updates on this framework?

Not at present. It is theoretically possible that announcements will appear on [the Android Developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/), but there has been no discussion of Volley there to date.

What may happen is that some small group of developers will take it upon themselves to provide Volley "releases", perhaps via Maven, where they will use some back-door channels into Google to try to determine when such releases should be made.

Personally, I will use other solutions, like [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), or maybe [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion), where at least I have a snowball's chance in Ft. Lauderdale of knowing when it is time to upgrade my app.